# MySQL querying multiple tables with concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM blogs;    
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
| id | title                       | content     |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+
|  1 | article about js & jquery   | lorem ipsum |
|  2 | article about php & mysql   | lorem ipsum |
|  3 | article about rails & mysql | lorem ipsum |
|  4 | article about rails & js    | lorem ipsum |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+

mysql> select * FROM categories;
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | javascript    |  
|  2 | jquery        |
|  3 | php           |
|  4 | mysql         |
|  5 | ruby-on-rails |
+----+---------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM blogs_categories;
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | blog_id | category_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 |           1 | 
|  2 |       1 |           2 |
|  3 |       2 |           3 |
|  4 |       2 |           4 |
|  5 |       3 |           4 |
|  6 |       3 |           5 |
|  7 |       4 |           1 |
|  8 |       4 |           5 |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

**QUESTION :** How do I get all blogs by a category but give me all categories related to the blog itself?

Example: I want to get all blogs in category `mysql`.

So far i have tried this query :

```
SELECT
  blogs.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name SEPARATOR ",") AS categories
FROM
  blogs
INNER JOIN
  blogs_categories
  ON blogs.id = blogs_categories.blog_id
INNER JOIN
  categories
  ON categories.id = blogs_categories.category_id
WHERE
  categories.name = 'mysql'
GROUP BY
  blogs.id
```

But it gives me unexpected result :

```
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+------------+
| id | title                       | content     | categories |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+------------+
|  2 | article about php & mysql   | lorem ipsum | mysql      |
|  3 | article about rails & mysql | lorem ipsum | mysql      |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+------------+
```

My desired result is :

```
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| id | title                       | content     | categories               |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|  2 | article about php & mysql   | lorem ipsum | php,mysql                |
|  3 | article about rails & mysql | lorem ipsum | mysql,ruby-on-rails      |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

How can I achieved this? Is it possible to do this in a single query?

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1780/5)**

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: just remove `WHERE
  categories.name = 'mysql'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use post aggregation check,`WHERE` refers to the columns in `SELECT` so it restricts them,`HAVING` refers to values in the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
  blogs.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name ) AS categories
FROM
  blogs
INNER JOIN
  blogs_categories
  ON blogs.id = blogs_categories.blog_id
 JOIN
  categories
  ON categories.id = blogs_categories.category_id
GROUP BY
  blogs.id
HAVING
  SUM(categories.name='mysql')>0
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1780/17

Comment: Thanks, Mihai. +1 for for a single query.